# How to apply SRP to user interface classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, single-responsibility-principle

My application uses a DI framework and follows "program to an interface" practice wherever necessary.

I use constructor injection since I'd like to see the dependencies explicitly. But now the constructors of my form classes take too many parameters (>=4 e.g).

**Question**: Since UI design doesn't usually adhere to SRP, a Winform class might have `n` constructor dependencies. Do you like to leave them as they are, pass a proxy object instead, use a service locator...? Also do you inject "aspects" (logger, etc) in every constructor, given that no aop-framework is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason why UI implementations should not adhere to SRP. Using patterns such as MVP, MVC or MVVM, a UI class' **single responsibility** is to to render and collect data through the UI. This is often best done through rather passive data structures such as View Models.

The issue about **constructor over-injection** should be addressed by [refactoring to Aggregate Services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx).

Aspects are best addressed through [application of the Decorator design pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/07/DependencyInjectionIsLooseCoupling.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Both articles are great. I'd like to open the "SRP in UI design" part a bit though. How do you cope with non-standard UI-requirements of customer? For example, forms involving multiple responsibilities (according to your design at-hand)...I think one might use compound views each employing SRP in itself, or might reconsider the granularity of responsibilities (as in Aggregate Services). What path would you take?

Comment: Compounds views sounds very reasonable. Each address a small subset of a larger problem set. That was basically the path taken by the now more or less defunct Composite Application Block.